# Upload chunked video to Twitter with spring-social-twitter / postman

Tags: java, video, twitter, postman, spring-social-twitter

I am currently trying to build an application to post videos to Twitter on behalf of a user.

So I currently have the `application-key`, `application-secret`,  `access-token` and `access-secret`.

```java
final TwitterTemplate twitterTemplate = new TwitterTemplate(
    "application-key",
    "application-secret",
    "access-token",
    "access-secret");
```

So using this I can actually post a tweet containing **only** text. 
If I want to include an image I have to include the workaround "solution" posted on a [bug](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-social/issues/317) of spring-social-twitter. This resolves the image but the video still cannot be uploaded.

So the rational thinking was to try out this upload with postman to "isolate" the call itself.

[image: Auth1 of postman]

In the previous image we can see the Authorization process. This is the same for **Every single call** I make.

with this Auth a simple `POST` to `https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json?status=hello` works. Same with 2 calls for image.

1. `POST` to `https://upload.twitter.com/1.1/media/upload.json?media_category=tweet_image` for the image upload ( body -> media : image ).
2. `POST` to `https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json` merge the media_id with a new tweet.

But back to the video following again the official guide of [twitter](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/media/upload-media/api-reference/post-media-upload-init) when I send this
[image: video init req]

the response is

[image: could not auth resp]

when the request media_type does not contain `/` then a valid response will return from tweeter with a media_id, lets call it `X`.
So I append a video ( second command ) on `X` and then finalize the video ( third command ) on `X`. But as expected the response is

[image: unrecognized media resp]

as the media_type was never provided. On the other hand if the video on the second step is pushed as base64 encoded ( and including the header for base64 encoding) then a response of

[image: invalid size resp]

No matter what I have done so far I cannot make it post a video. I even used Postman as a proxy for twurl and captured the request of twurl that **did** upload the video. Changed the auth with mine ( because of nonce it requires to be recreated ) and the request failed to upload the video!

some notes :

1. the credentials are up to dates and work from twurl.
2. the video is valid and can be uploaded from both tweeter ui and twurl upload command.
3. the base64 convert was encoded / decoded with linux base64 tool piped to file and validated that the size is the same.

If any other clarification is required please let me know!

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I know it's late but in case someone has same question,
to upload video on twitter you have to use chunked-media-upload method.

here's the reference
https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/media/upload-media/uploading-media/chunked-media-upload

Comment: This is what i was using if you check the links I wrote above :/

Comment: @MichaelMichailidis 
you should have tried by sending data in body form data
instead of query string
it worked for me